# Use 1 Application gateway with 1 custom domain for 2 app services that host the same application code for different environments

Tags: azure, networking, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway, azure-appservice

I want to use a single application gateway to route traffic to 2 application services to save costs, while still getting the security benefits of WAF.

-Both application services are hosting the same application code with minor differences appearing between versions/environments.

-If using a custom domain, I would need/like to use a single custom domain and multiple sub-domains created from it to access the app services (the APIs). I am not confident if that is possible.

-I cannot seem to find the above described use case/solution in the documentation, so any working approach that achieves my end goal, but deviates from my idea would be appreciated.

-My networking is quite weak, but I do understand basic terminology. Detailed explanations on how to handle the networking portion of the problem would be a blessing (DNS records, custom domains, host names in application gateway etc.). I am not sure how to create sub domains, how to connect them to different AGW pools and everything in between.

DISCLAIMER:
This is my first question on SF. If the question is unclear or unsatisfactory in any way, shape or form, it will be updated as promptly as possible.

Official documentation on this topic, as well as the unofficial one was read before posting this question. The question is here, because I, the author was not able to piece together a working solution after reading majority of the resources at least once, if not several times.

Attempt 1 - Route based.

I tried to setup a route based routing rule, expecting to get different applications when accessing the application gateway public ip/DNS name. The redirection to different pools worked, but the section of the url specified in the route was appended to each request, thus preventing me from accessing the same path on different apps/environments.

Config 1:

2 pools tied to 1 app service each

HTTPS backend setting:

- Override with new host
- Pick host name from backend target
- Trusted certificate (default app service certificate)

1 basic listener on port 80

1 Path based routing rule that includes 2 pools from above

Config outcome:

www.APPGATEWAYPUBLICIP/app1/swagger/index.html and www.APPGATEWAYPUBLICIP/app2/swagger/index.html
DO redirect to different pools, but the /app1 or /app2 sections are always appended to the app service URL, thus preventing me from accessing the swagger/index.html path that's present on both apps.
FAILURE

Attempt 2 - Back to basics.

Config 2:

2 pools tied to 1 app service each

2 HTTPS back-end settings with same config as rule above in attempt 1

2 basic listeners on port 80 for each pool

2 basic rules for each listener/pool

Config outcome:

-I do not even understand how I would access the different apps through the AGW pip/DNS name

-Accessing app services directly doesn't go through the AGW pip, but through the default app service ip addresses. If I had a custom domain, I imagine I would need records that lead to the AGW, but I'm unable to find a fully flashed out example of this configuration.

-Using 2 custom domains with 2 listeners, rules... would work, but seems wrong when used for a single application (same app code on 2 different app services

CUSTOM DOMAIN CONFIG:

I did not attempt configuring the custom domain/certificate part since the basic structure of the solution is not yet fully clear to me.

Adding a self signed certificate was attempted, but dropped until I know that this solution is viable at all for production use cases.

Using a domain bought in Azure would be preferred, but not mandatory. Once purchased, how would it interact the the Azure DNS zone and the rest of the config?

Documentation shows binding a single domain to a single app service and single pool/listener/rule, but does not go into detail. Other sources show the basic config tried in the 2 attempts above, but they do not achieve the outcome that I want.

Answer (score 0):

> ***Note***: According to this [document](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2017/08/08/FAQ-App-Service-Domain-and-Custom-Domains.html) by *mksunitha* it is not possible to use the same custom domain for 2 different App service. Custom domain with `www.domin.com` can be added for one web App, you need to use another subdomain `xyz.mydomain.com` but you cannot use `www.domain.com`.

Generally, it's not recommended to add the same domain to a web app in same region. According to your scenario, you can create one App service with one region and resource group and create another App service with different region and different resource group.

Doing it for a failover scenario accessing both the backend pools simultaneously. If it is in the same resource group, you will not be able to add the same custom domain.

I have created two App services with different resource group and regions. In the Application gateway added 1 backend pool for 2 App services:

[image]

Once the backend pool is added create DNS zone, The DNS zone name should be the name of purchased domain name and add 'A' record set with application gateway public IP.

[image]

***In your custom domain -> DNS -> Managed zone ->add domain name `domain.com` -> In down, click nameserver and change. replace all the name server of Azure like `ns1-XXX.azure-dns.com` without dot (.) and save -> continue.***

[image]

Now, add one backend setting, listener, and associate it with rule:

[image]

***Rule***:

[image]

Now, when I hit the domain name its redirect to the backend target and change both of the target successfully like below:

[image]

When you deploy an App service a certain resource group as web space, when deploying multiple App service into a single resource group, all the App services shares the same web space. But if you change the resource group of App service, web space becomes different from resource group to resource group. So web space will be different. For using that scenario, you can add the same custom domain to both the app services. Then point that custom domain to App service DNS name and use it in the back end like a normal load balancing scenario.

***Reference***:

[What setup should I use to host a web app with 2 backends - Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1336597/what-setup-should-i-use-to-host-a-web-app-with-2-b)  by *Gitarani*

Comment: @Imran, hello. Thanks for answering. This is not quite what I was asking. I'm fine with using different sub-domains for different apps like 'app1.domain.com' and 'app2.domain.com. Apps are in different resource groups so that's not a problem. I don't want 2 apps in the same pool. I want the same app (with minor differences between environments/apps) in 2 different pools, that I can access through those 2 domains. I want to be able to access to different environments through the same AGW. I hope I made the question clearer. Thanks once again.